# Iterating over TR in a table with Cheerio.js

Tags: jquery, node.js, cheerio

I'm having issues using the selectors that are available for Cheerio.js that I use on my Node server. The core is supposedly based on jQuery, however I can't really make it work using the same selection I would with native jQuery.

I have a DOM that roughly looks like this:

```
<div class="test">
    <table class="listing">
        <thead><tr>few cells here</tr></thead>
        <tfoot></tfoot>
        <tbody><tr>These are the rows I want</tr></tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Since there are two tables on the page with the class "listing" I can't select that directly so I need the reference to the div with the "test" class. The selection I can run with jQuery would be something like:

```
$('div.test tbody tr')
```

But this doesn't work with Cheerio. If I run $('div[class="test"] tr') I get all the rows on the table, even the thead rows, so that doesn't work for me.

Any guesses?

**Update:**
This is the actual code I'm executing (does not work):

```
// Load the html
var $ = cheerio.load(html, {
    normalizeWhitespace: true
});

$('div.tillgodo tbody tr').each(function(){
    console.log("Found credited course...");
    var children = $(this).children();
    var credits = parseFloat($(children[3]).text().replace(',', '.')); // We need to replace comma with a dot since parseFloats only supports dots by design

    var row = {
        "course" : $(children[1]).text().trim(),
        "grade" : null,
        "credits" : credits,
        "date" : $(children[4]).text()
    };

    // Push course to JSON object
    console.log("Push course to object...");
    console.log("------------------------------------------\n");
    data.credited_courses.push(row);
    data.credited_courses_credits += parseFloat(credits);
});
```

The following code works for the **first** table:

```
$('tr.incomplete.course').each(function(i, tr){
    console.log("This is course nr: " + parseInt(course_count+1));
    console.log("Found incompleted course...");
    var children = $(this).children();
    var credits = parseFloat($(children[2]).text().replace(',', '.').match(/(\+|-)?((\d+(\.\d+)?)|(\.\d+))/)[0]); // Filter out any parentheses and odd characters
    var row = {
        "course" : $(children[1]).text(),
        "grade" : $(children[3]).text(),
        "credits" : credits,
        "date" : $(children[5]).text()
    };

    // Sum the total amount of credits for all courses
    console.log("Add credits to incompleted_credits...");
    data.incompleted_credits += credits;

    console.log("Push course to object...");
    data.incompleted_courses.push(row);
    course_count++;
});
```

When I say that it doesn't work means that the JSON object I'm returning does not have the expected rows from the second table.

**Update 2**
The table I want to scrape:

```
<div class="tillgodo">
    <h2>Tillgodoräknanden</h2>
    <table class="listing">
    <thead>
    <tr class="listingHeader">
        <th>Kurskod</th>
        <th>Kursnamn</th>
        <th>Beslutsfattare</th>
        <th class="credits">Poäng</th>
        <th>Datum</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
    <tr class="listingTrailer">
        <td>
        </td><td colspan="2">Summa tillgodoräknade poäng:
        </td><td class="credits">10,5
        </td><td>
    </td></tr>
    </tfoot>
    
        <tbody><tr>
            <td>
            </td><td>Valfria kurser
            </td><td>xxx
            </td><td class="credits">10,5
            </td><td class="nobreak">2013-06-03
        </td></tr>
    
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: Post your code, please. I loaded your HTML and iterated through the `tr` elements just fine using the selector you are using. I suspect your selector is OK but you aren't using the cheerio API correctly in your javascript.

Comment: Ok, no problem. Updated the question with the actual code.

Comment: I think this is a case where you should create a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In scraping code like this, everything about the HTML, selectors, and javascript has to align. The devil is in the details. Your code looks fragile but without an MCVE we can't help beyond "don't make any mistakes".

Comment: I understand that it is hard to help. I can provide the HTML for the table I want to scrape as a last resort :)

Comment: Check your version of cheerio? When I run your code I get the single "Valfria kurser" row which seems correct based on your snippets. I'm using cheerio 0.18.0.

Comment: Finally I found the problem... The actualy source code for the page is poor. The rows that was ending up wrapped in a tbody actually was just outside the tfoot tag with no wrapper whatsoever. So Chrome which I was using was fixing the issue and put it in a tbody, which didn't exists (which was why I didn't find anything). When I was posting the code here I inspected the DOM and copy and pasted it here, not from the source. Now I have to use another selector hehe.

Comment: Sounds like you're comparing the source to chrome's html5 interpretation of it (the elements panel)

Comment: Please do not add answers to the question body itself. Instead, you should add it as an answer. [Answering your own question is allowed and even encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The selector I had been using all along was working. But the source HTML was malformed and had no tbody tag at all. The browser (Chrome in my case) fixed the problem but made it hard to find the real issue.

[Answer from OP; originally edited into the question itself](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/28387327/4)

Answer (score -1):

you can try `$(div.test table.listing tr).text()`

This will give you the text from all the tr tags in that table

Comment: how do i do this with `id` though?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but almost always, this isn't a good approach. This merges all of the row's contents into one giant text string, defeating the purpose of the table to organize data. Generally, you'd want to use something like `[...$("div.test table.listing tr")].map(e => [...$(e).find("td")].map(e => $(e).text()))` which preserves each cell's data in a matrix data structure. Also, this answer's code is missing string quotes so it's not valid syntax, and OP's problem is that they have a malformed structure in any event.